# _ (underscore) is getting appended to clases in Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am observing some strange behaviour in angular-material and not understanding if its a bug or expected behaviour. Below is the scss code snippet which works on server but not on my local environment.

```
md-radio-button, md-checkbox{
    border-color: #0FA3BC;
    &.md-checked{
        .md-icon{
            background-color: #0FA3BC;
        }
    }
    .md-on{
        background-color: #0FA3BC;
    }
}
```

and below is HTML snippet.

```
 <md-radio-group ng-model="delivery.requiredoneoption" ng-if="delivery.deliveryoptions.required_parts.select_one" ng-change="delivery.informUser(parts.part_number)">
    <md-radio-button ng-repeat="parts in delivery.selectedParts" ng-value="parts.part_number" >
            {{parts.product_name}} - {{parts.price | currency}}
     </md-radio-button>
 </md-radio-group>
```

After some analysis, I observed that in my local setup, Angular-material is prepending _ (underscore) to `md-on` class and making it `_md-on`. Same about `_md-off`.

If you check the source code of one of the theme from material's source code they are also using a class as `md-on` and `md-off`
https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/radioButton/radio-button-theme.scss
I cleared the cache couple of times but no luck. Code in both the environments is exactly same.

Comment: Even angular-material demo on official website is having _ in class.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/radioButton

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional, because classes, which are prefixed with an underscore, are indicating that those classes are internal and can change at any time.

Also this prefixing with the underscore, has been removed a few days ago.
The classes will be without the underscore in v1.1.0, which will come soon!